# @JsonKey how to access to elements of a Map, flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the next map `config`, I was wondering how I could access to it using the `@JsonKey` keyword.

[image]

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class UserModel {
  @JsonKey(name: 'username')
  String username;

  @JsonKey(name: 'realName')
  String realname;

  @JsonKey(name: 'gender')
  String gender;

  @JsonKey(name: 'date_birth')
  String dateBirth;

  @JsonKey(name: 'isObserver')
  bool isObserver;

  @JsonKey(name: 'friends')
  List<dynamic> friendsList;

  @JsonKey(name: 'pendingFriends')
  List<dynamic> pendingFriendsList;

  @JsonKey(name: 'config') // Here, config is a map, how can I access to their data?
  bool notifyFriend;

  UserModel(this.username, this.realname, this.dateBirth, this.gender,
      this.isObserver, this.friendsList, this.pendingFriendsList, this.notifyFriend);

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserModelToJson(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to create another class with the name config having those 3 variables in it and then import that class in this class and replace the variable there with that like :

```
class Config{
@JsonKey(name: 'notifyFriends')
  bool  notifyFriend;
@JsonKey(name: 'recordAudio')
  bool  recordAudio;
@JsonKey(name: 'sendTweet')
  bool  sendTweet;

Config(this.sendTweet, this.recordAudio, this.notifyFriend);

  factory Config.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ConfigFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ConfigToJson(this);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
@JsonKey(name: 'config') // Here,
  Config config;
```

I hope this clear your problem.